# Can a living thing be a Portkey?

Tags: harry-potter

Okay so I'm writing a Harry Potter fanfiction, and I'm wondering if a living thing could be used as a Portkey. You know, if someone were to just point at themselves and go "Portus".

Or if that's not possible, could they turn a piece of their clothing into a Portkey, like, say, a scarf they were wearing, and have it activate like any other object turned Portkey?

Comment: In a way, Apparition is an example of being your own Portkey, and others can move alongside just as they could with a portkey. The sensations of each are described differently but in both you DESignate a DELiberate DEStination. If a wizard could take out the DEtermination, and just have an outside spell do it for you, they probably would. Also, what we don't know is the skill it takes to create a Portkey. Maybe that is the true limitation. Only Dumbledore and ministry experts have been shown to have created Portkeys. The implication seems to be that it's prohibitively difficult to do.

Answer (score 9):

JKR's description of a 'Portkey' on the Pottermore website would suggest that portkeys can only be made from **objects**, not living things:

> **Almost any inanimate object can be turned into a Portkey. Once
>   bewitched, the object will transport anyone who grasps it to a
>   pre-arranged destination.** A Portkey may also be enchanted to transport
>   the grasper (or graspers) only at a given time. In this way, the
>   arrivals and departures of great numbers of witches and wizards can be
>   staggered, enabling such events such as the Quidditch World Cup to
>   take place with few security breaches. <sub><sup>[Pottermore Wiki](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Portkeys)</sup></sub>

The same quote also indicates that it must be "grasped". Enchanting a set of clothes in-situ would probably be quite effective (unless you can think of a way of getting them off without grasping them) although as a piece of offensive magic it would be relatively useless since the spell seems to require several seconds to take effect, long enough to remove the offending article.

> *"For a moment the kettle trembled, glowing with an odd blue light; then
>   it quivered to rest, as solidly black as ever."*
>   <sub><sup>OOTP</sup></sub>